# Geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung with or without comma

Tags: word-order, comma, attribute

In physics there is the term *geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung*/*geradlinige, gleichförmige Bewegung*. I wonder what the correct variant is. In my understanding, the variant with comma

> geradlinige, gleichförmige Bewegung

is correct, because the attributes *geradlinig* and *gleichförmig* are independant of each other. The rule says:

- If the attributes have the same rank, a comma must be written.
- If the attributes have different rank, a comma must not be written.
  If the attributes had different rank, there would be a difference in their order. But as they are independant, the order has no meaning. (*Geradlinige, gleichförmige Bewegung* means the same as *Gleichförmige, geradlinige Bewegung*)

Alas, must sources use the variant without comma

> geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung

So which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variants are correct and possible:

> geradlinige, gleichförmige Bewegung
>
> gleichförmige, geradlinige Bewegung

As you correctly write, attributes have the same rank here.

However, in German you can also express by grammar, that they don't have the same rank in the context you are talking about.

> geradlinig(e) gleichförmige Bewegung

"geradlinig" further specifies what kind of "gleichförmige Bewegung" you are referring to. You could use this if your topic are different kinds of "gleichförmige Bewegung".

> gleichförmig(e) geradlinige Bewegung

"gleichförmig" further specifies what kind of "geradlinige Bewegung" you are referring to. You could use this if your topic are different kinds of "geradlinige Bewegung".

I think "geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung" might be [a bit more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=31&smoothing=3&content=geradlinig+gleichf%C3%B6rmige+Bewegung%2Cgleichf%C3%B6rmig+geradlinige+Bewegung&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgeradlinig%20gleichf%C3%B6rmige%20Bewegung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgleichf%C3%B6rmig%20geradlinige%20Bewegung%3B%2Cc0) because kids learn first about "gleichförmige Bewegung", which is assumed to be "geradlinig", but often not called that until "Kreisbewegung" is introduced.

Comment: I think that *\*geradlinige gleichförmige Bewegung* is wrong. If *geradlinig* is an attribute to *gleichförmig*, it is supposed to be *geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung* (*geradlinig* would not be declined).

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I think both are possible. In "geradlinig gleichförmig" we further specify "gleichförmig". In "geradlinige gleichförmige Bewegung" we further specify the "gleichförmige Bewegung". There is a nuanced difference in meaning. I'm sure both are correct but I don't know the technical terms for this.

Comment: I guess you are right. I didn't see the possibility that *geradlinige* could refer to the whole termn *gleichförmige Bewegung*.

Answer (score -1):

I disagree with previous answer and with your assumption, that *geradlinig* and *gleichförmig* are independent of each other, therefore I see no benefit in discussing their ranks.

I consider *geradlinig gleichförmige Bewegung* as a technical term (see [Lexikon der Physik](https://www.spektrum.de/lexikon/physik/geradlinige-bewegung/5760)) and *geradlinig* on its own does not sufficiently clarify, what kind of movement you have.

Note, that according to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Komma-zwischen-Adjektiven) adding an adjective to a fixed term already having one adjective permits no comma.

Comment: The link contradicts your answer. Its heading is already "geradlinige Bewegung".

Comment: Also, the technical term is "Translation".

Comment: I don't consider this an answer to the question. Even if it is a technical term, it still would need to be clarified why *geradlinige, gleichförmige Bewegung* should be considered wrong. I also miss an argument why you disagree with the reasoning of Ronald's answer, which seems fine to me. Hence I give -1 here.

Comment: Also it is pretty unclear what you mean by "sufficiently". This term seems to come out of the blue, because what is sufficient information, depends on context. So your argument, that the two adjectives cannot be (grammatically) independent, seems to be based on weak ground.